# HTML Iframe within page content

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, user-interface

I have a huge content in an HTML page and i want to put the same within iframe. But putting the content within iframe tag within page, page shows that part as blank. Please suggest how does we put content within iframe in the same HTML. What should be placed in src if applying the same page content.

```
<iframe src="">
//Content
</iframe>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend that if you want to place a large section of your current page's output into a scrollable area of your page, don't use an iframe, instead do something like this:

```
<div style="overflow-y: auto; width: 100%; height: 400px;">
  <!-- put all of your large amount of content after this comment, before the closing div tag -->
  <p>this is my huge amount of content (just an example.... you'd have hundreds of lines of code here I suspect</p>
</div>
```

Of course you can change the height and width of the div to suit your needs.

the div style="overflow-y: auto;" with a specified width and height should (I think) create a scrollable area in your page similar to the output of an iframe, but without requiring the browser to load two copies of the contents.  Also you avoid the possibility of an infinite loop.

you could also add a border around the area if you like, for example after height: 400px; by changing the first line to this:

```
<div style="overflow-y: auto; width: 100%; height: 400px; border: 2px solid grey;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You would put the link to the page you need to display the content from

```
<iframe src="http://www.yoursite.com"></iframe>
```

> src = URL potentially surrounded by spaces Gives the address of a page
>   that the nested browsing context is to contain.

read up on [iframes](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Say for example all of your HTML is inside index.html, simply set the `src` attribute to `index.html`.

Like so:

```
<iframe src="index.html"></iframe>
```

Remember, this doesn't necessarily work correctly as you'll run the `<iframe>` into a continuous loop. Though, correct me if I'm wrong, it will only repeat the iframe twice as a security policy.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="URL or pagename.html"></iframe>
```